# How to add an HTML <rel=preload> tag to the header in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, header

ho to all the free folks!

Since the google speed insights report suggests adding a

```
<link rel="preload" href="/file-name.css" as="style"/>
```

to speed up the loading of the following resources

https://www.myoutlet.lt/wp-content/plugins/gdpr-cookie-compliance/dist/styles/lity.css

on the website https://www.myoutlet.lt

I am wondering how could I possibly achieve that!

There should be for sure some way to inject an HTML-tag into the header by means of recurring to some PHP-function in the functions.php or header.php file. As a junior SEO, I have some technical understanding, but I'm quite far from being a developer.

The one who will show me the way will earn my eternal gratitude! Thank you very much in advance for any valuable hint.

P.S.: I have to achieve this manually, without any plugins (the website is already quite slow!); the WP-website is based on the Avada Theme

On another tech forum, I was suggested to add the following snippet to the functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'se343581_add_preload_tag', 5);
function se343581_add_preload_tag()
{
echo '<link rel="preload" href="'. 
     plugins_url('/gdpr-cookie-compliance/dist/styles/lity.css') .
     '" as="style">';
//
// -- if added in plugin file --
// echo '<link rel="preload" href="' . plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 
//'some_subdir/file_name.css" as="style">';
}
```

That user asserted that this snippet was good to go as it is. I´ve tried it out in both the main theme and the child-theme function.php file, without success.

Is there anyone out there able to help me a little bit out?

May the force be with you, Roman

Answer (score 1):

Check on what theme your site is using and inside that theme look for template file `header.php`. Most likely that's the place where you have to insert your code (again depending on theme).

For more details check on this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/

Comment: It did not work out in the header.php. The problem is still not solved! Maybe anyone else has a better suggestion?

Comment: Did you find that file? Edited it? Was the change visible in page source?

Comment: Hi again! Found it, edited it, no change visible in page source.

Comment: Comapare surrounding code in page source with the one in template you found. If that's the one then it must be some caching problem. If not...search for the right template file.

Comment: Dragi Milane, kad ti budem posalio sustav functions.php tog websajta, da li bi ti mozda mogao lijepo kratko zaviriti u taj file? Dosta je jaka vjerovatnost da bilo ista sam pogresio s "sintaksisom" koda, kao obican junior SEO manager ne razumjem se ja previse u PHP. Kaj mislis na to? :) Drugarski pozdrav